# Time is not synced in centos7.3

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, time-synchronization

I have installed stock CentOS7.3, and install `chrony`

```
yum install -y chrony
systemctl start chronyd
systemctl enable chronyd
```

If I start CentOS, the time is not synced:

```
$ timedatectl
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
```

chrony is running, though

```
$ systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-06-02 12:19:35 JST; 17min ago
  Process: 631 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/chrony-helper update-daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 608 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/chronyd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 620 (chronyd)
   Memory: 1.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
           └─620 /usr/sbin/chronyd
```

I have to do a manually `sudo systemctl restart chronyd` to fix the time syncing problem.

Why is that.

Answer (score 1):

NTP takes some time to synchronize. It needs a couple data points, which takes a minute or two.

You can watch the state of peers with commands like `chronyc sources`. Each server should have a packet received recently, the LastRx column.

timedatectl determines NTP status via the kernel time discipline. It calls adjtimex() and returns false on an error or if STA_UNSYNC.  See systemd sources, time-util.c.

Comment: I waited 30mins, still no luck. `[root@localhost ~]# chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 4
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^+ laika.paina.net               2   6   371    11   -231us[ -231us] +/-   35ms
^- jp.dan.me.uk                  2   6   277    11    +11ms[  +11ms] +/-  185ms
^* chobi.paina.net               2   6   377    15   -287us[ -382us] +/-   21ms
^+ sjkBBML24.bb.kddi.ne.jp       5   6   377    12   +794us[ +794us] +/-   59ms`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `timedatectl` to instruct your OS to accurately maintain the correct time by keeping its time in sync with an another trusted remote “NTP” server. This is done by running the following command:

```
timedatectl set-ntp yes
```

We can view a list of trusted ntp servers that the chronyd is using to sync the system-time. You can view this list using the chronyc command:

```
chronyc sources -v
```

Also, check the system file  in which NTP servers are updated

```
cat /etc/chrony.conf

# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).

server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst             
server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst      
server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst         
server 3.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Alternatively you can also update the ntp server with time zone

```
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/London
```